# PHP Json response formatting

Tags: php, json

I have the following script that returns a json response.

```
$response["customer_creds"] =array(array('customer_names'=>$user['name'], 'customer_email' => $user['email'], 'customer_id' => $user['customer_id'], 'customer_type' => $user['customer_type'], 'rating' => $user['rating']));
```

The above script returns:

```
"customer_creds": [
    {
      "customer_names": "John Doe",
      "customer_email": "example@example.com",
      "customer_id": "123456",
      "customer_type": "1",
      "rating": "4"
    }
  ],
```

Now I want my json to return the customer_type as an object.`("customer_type": [1],`

I have tried  json decoding and encoding on the same script but nothing seems to work. Any workarounds on this? At a later stage I'll want to have my json to return multiple customer types. The final response should be something like this:

```
"customer_creds": [
  {
      "customer_names": "John Doe",
      "customer_email": "example@example.com",
      "customer_id": "123456",
      "customer_type": [1,2,3],
      "rating": "4"
    }
  ],
```

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If you want `customer_type'` to be an array, then assign an array: `'customer_type' => array(...)`. This has nothing to do with JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just want the `customer_type` to be an array of values, instead of just one value?

```
$response["customer_creds"] = array(
    array(
        'customer_names' => $user['name'], 
        'customer_email' => $user['email'], 
        'customer_id' => $user['customer_id'], 
        'customer_type' => array($user['customer_type']), // Just wrap it with array()
        'rating' => $user['rating']
    )
);
```

Comment: it returns "customer_type": [
        "1"
      ], and i want "customer_type": [
        1
      ],

Comment: @nick isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: @nick oh you want an integer `1` instead of a string `"1"`? Just put `intval()` around the `$user['customer_type']`.

Comment: a problem is actuakky coming up when i return an array of values. It just returns the first value when i use 'customer_type' => array(intval($user['customer_type']).','.intval($user['customer_driver'])),

Comment: @nick: You need to learn how arrays work: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php. You are trying to perform string concatenation. An array is not a string.